# What is the correct way to handle an accesstoken with react to secure routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an express backend which on login returns an access token as a response and a refresh token as a cookie

```
      const sendAccessToken = (res , req, accesstoken) => {
        res.send({
            accesstoken,
            email: req.body.email

        })
    }

const sendRefreshToken = (res, refreshtoken) => {
    res.cookie("refreshtoken", refreshtoken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/refresh_token'
    })
}
```

Point is I need to have something similar to an Authservice in my react frontend to check if that access token is valid , it should return something like. True if access token is valid, and false if acces token is invalid, and based on that it will allow access the different routes I have in my react frontend. (I want to implement it right into the switch if possible)

HOw should I approach it?

I remember using an auth guard approach in angular, but since im new to react im not sure
I used to do something like this where canActivate had true or false values:

```
    ...
import { RoleGuard } from '../guards/role-guard.service';
...
children:[
   ...,
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard],
    data: {role: 'Admin'}
  },
  ...
];
```

SO as pseudocode in my react it should look like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
    <Route  exact path="/register" render={(props) => <RegisterPage />} />
    <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => <LoginPage />} />
    <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <NewLandingPage {...props} />} />
    <Route path="/protectedRoute" canActivate = [Guard] render={(props) => <Prueba {...props} />} /> 
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

But appart from that. How am I supposed to check that the returned access token is valid using the front end? (I obtain them with refresh tokens) Since isnt it supposed to happen in the back end? Because the secrets to decode the token are in the backend, i dont know how to check it in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your approach you can do something like this :

```
state = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
}

//in render : 

return (
  <div>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => ((this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <Home {...props}/> : <Login {...props}/>)}/>
        <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => ((this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <Home {...props}/> : <Login {...props}/>)}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```